# Fitting text to the maximum width of a div

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to learn HTML and CSS by creating a portfolio website and can't past through this problem.
What I want to achieve is to reduce the 'Source code' width and fit to the upper div called 'Project #'.
Also tried with tables but the result is kinda meh.
Do I miss something or should I just change my strategy to solve this problem?
This is the A element:

```
.projects-table a {
font-size: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
border: solid 2px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
color: #00CF80;
}
```

And here is a link to the full code:
https://codepen.io/xAndreei/pen/BGyNVe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you probably just need

```
display: block;
```

added to your CSS rule for the `<a>`, since an  element has a default of `display:inline`.

more about CSS Display Property:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/